# Validate nested JSON in POJO using annotation in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation

I have a JSON which I would like to validate.

```
{
  "a": {
    "attribute1": "",
    "attribute2": ""
  },
  "b": {
    "attribute3": "1240717"
  },
  "c": {
    "attribute4": "1321"
  },
  "d": "Lab",
  "c": {
    "attribute5": "2021-09-06T20:42:48",
    "attribute6": "2021-09-06T20:42:48"
  }
}
```

I would like to check a NotNull condition with @NotNull in POJO class on attribute3, attribute4, attribute5 and attribute6 which are nested.
I tried this

```
public class JsonValidator {
    
    @NonNull
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
    @NotEmpty(message = "Bad request")
    private String attribute3;
    @NonNull
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String attribute4;
    @NonNull
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String attribute5;
    @NonNull
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String attribute6;
```

But it is only working when the attributes are not nested in another object and present in root object.
Can anyone tell how can I achieve this

Comment: For starters `@NotBlank` already means the same thing as `@Nonnull @NotEmpty`. You also didn't show your top-level class; is the nested property marked `@Valid`?

Comment: Annotate your complex object with `@Valid`. Then validation will trigger for the nested properties according to how they are defined.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll try that

Comment: Did it work? If not can you add the complete model with all the relevant classes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to annotate your complex object with the @Valid annotation. This will y=then trigger the nested properties.

Comment: Used "@Valid" but it was still not working as expected. Had to add "@JsonProperty" then it worked. But Thank you all of you for the input